# Can Firebase database used for both android and website

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an app with  firebase as database. And i am creating a website with the same data as in app. can i use same database for both app and website. when data update take place in app should also be resembled  in website and vice versa

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask);  if you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem;  also, remember to include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);  people will be glad to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is definitely possible. For example, the FriendlyPix sample app is available for iOS, Android, and Web, and all these talks to the same back-end services. So photos posted in one platform show up in all other platforms too.